# residualize binary outcome variable

Tags: regression, logistic, residuals, binary-data

Does it make sense and what is the correct approach to residualize a binary variable? For a continuous variable `y`, I simply run a regression that predicts `y` as a function of `x` and subtract `y_hat=xb` (the predicted valable of y from the regression) from `y`. Can I use the same procedure for a binary variable `y` so that `y_hat=invlogit(xb)` and the residualized variable ranges from -1 to 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

If I understand your set-up, your observations $y_t$ are binary: $y_t \in \{0,1\}$ for all $t$. Your predictions $\hat{y}_t$ take values on the unit interval: $\hat{y}_t \in [0,1]$ for all $t$. Errors are given by the difference between the true value and the predicted value, as usual: $e_t = \hat{y}_t - y_t$.

The specific prediction or estimation procedure you are using does not matter for this definition.

A related issue -- perhaps one that motivates your question? -- concerns how you should evaluate the quality of your prediction system. There are a number of different [scoring rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoring_rule) that one could use to score a forecasting system that generates probabilistic forecasts of a dichotomous variable. A standard one is the [Brier Score](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brier_score).

Comment: I find it important to make the following observation: What @arthur suggests are the so-called response residuals. There are many others. Because of the link function, there is no single definition of what a model residual is in GLM. There are the deviance, working, partial and pearson residuals too.

Comment: thanks, very helpful! I am not really interested in evaluating the quality of fit. Instead, I want to use the residualized variable as the outcome variable in another regression. The reason why I do not simply include `x` in the regression is that my regression is local   and restricted to a very small bandwidth with a rectangular kernel.